# How to get a contents of a file and save it in a variable inside a pod from a node?

Tags: bash, kubernetes

I am writing a automation script to be run from  a pod. I want to get the contents of a file inside a pod and save it in a variable.

The file is:

```
$ cat ip_addr.txt
10.120.2.21
```

My code is:

```
kubectl exec -it --namespace=<namespace name> <pod name> -- bash -c "elastisearch=$(cat ipaddr.txt)"
```

when i run other commands like ls or cd it runs fine

When I run `elastisearch=$(cat ipaddr.txt)` inside the pod it runs fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you want to use this variable elasticsearch? In your script?

Comment: @yayotron inside the pod

Comment: you might be better of saving that address file as part of a ConfigMap and mount it, or alternatively put it as an env variable directly. Any reason you want to exec this into the pod somehow?

Answer (score 0):

When you set a variable with

```
kubectl exec -it --namespace=<namespace name> <pod name> -- bash -c "elastisearch=$(cat ipaddr.txt)"
```

you set it for this session and this session only. Session ends when the command ends.
What happens in your case is

1. start a session with `bash`
2. pass a command to it `elastisearch=$(cat ipaddr.txt)`
3. variable `elastisearch` is set
4. command ends successfully
5. session ends, shell is destroyed and variable `elastisearch` with it

---

You have three possible solutions:

- Run a command that requires variable `elastisearch` in the same session e.g.:

```
kubectl exec -it --namespace=<namespace name> <pod name> -- bash -c "elastisearch=$(cat ipaddr.txt); some_other_command_that_need_this_variable"
```

- [Define an environment variable for a container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#define-an-environment-variable-for-a-container)

```yaml
...
spec:
  containers:
  - name: <app-name>
    image: <app-image>
    env:
    - name: elastisearch
      value: "10.120.2.21"
...
```

- Bake a variable into your image with [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env)

```
ENV elastisearch="10.120.2.21"
```